# How to make Windows XP USB flash install media under Linux?

Tags: linux, windows-xp, usb, bootable-media, windows-installer

I have:

- ISO image of Windows XP install media
- 4 GB USB flash drive
- no CD/DVD drive
- Linux (Linux Mint 14) installed

**Note**:

1. [WinToFlash](http://wintoflash.com/home/en/) is for Windows OS.
2. [UNetBootIn](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) doesn't work unless you've tried.
3. [Gunthers' answer here](https://serverfault.com/questions/6714/how-to-make-windows-7-usb-flash-install-media-from-linux/167060#167060) doesn't seems to work for Windows XP.
4. No, I do not want a Windows 7 USB boot installation.
5. Lastly, this is not a duplicate of [Make a bootable usb to install Windows XP from Linux](https://superuser.com/questions/99478/make-a-bootable-usb-to-install-windows-xp-from-linux). *(That user wants to install Windows XP into his Dell Mini 9. But I want to make a USB for Windows XP installation)*

Comment: Give a try to this [tutorial](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/multiboot-create-a-multiboot-usb-from-linux/). I'm not sure if that works only for making live USB of Linux.

Comment: Nonono. Just to clarify, I want to make a USB bootable installer; not a live USB. But I will give it a try anyway.

Comment: I know what exactly you want to do that's why I said "I'm not sure" :)

Comment: Thanks for showing effort. I've tried and managed to boot into some GRUB but I don't know how to continue from there. In the meantime, I've also been looking at [ms-sys](http://ms-sys.sourceforge.net/) for some time and I still fail. I **believe** it is capable though.

Answer (score 0):

What you need is Unetbootin build 494. This particular build allows to use NTFS volumes instead of ext4/MBR and others present in versions beside this one.

note: you have to format the USB to the desired FS before running Unetbootin.