# Unable to install Windows XP in a Toshiba Satellite with Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, windows-xp, boot, bootable-media

I have a **Toshiba Satellite L305D** notebook that had Windows 7 on it.

I recently installed **Ubuntu** on a partition and uninstalled Windows erasing its partition and its "System reserved" one, leaving a large **unallocated space at the beginning** of the hard drive; then updated grub.

Now I'm trying to install **Windows XP** Pro SP3, with no luck.

With an ISO image downloaded from Microsoft website, I prepared a **bootable USB** that works in a Dell Windows 7 notebook but doesn't in my Toshiba! Same goes for bootable DVD. And it does boot other stuff such as Ubuntu installer and GParted Live, but not Win XP installer.

When I try to boot it, the screen goes black a second and then loads Ubuntu like normal startup. BIOS doen't have UEFI capability, so that isn't the problem. Also tried swiching SATA mode from AHCI to Compatibility mode, but did nothing. Not much interesting options in the BIOS settings. Any ideas?

Comment: Windows XP predates USB installs. Its also EOL - you're better off running it as a VM

Comment: @JourneymanGeek he says it works in a dell windows 7 notebook

Comment: How did you make the win xp installation USB?  I don't think i've done it for XP, and I know win7 has a tool for making a win7 install from usb. But you could try WinToFlash that's what this guy uses https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XqO4fEDV7R0   you could try unetbootin but maybe you tried that.

Comment: @barlop I used Rufus that [apparently](http://superuser.com/a/623998/621637) is the most convenient for Win XP installer. I guess I could try other tools, but the thing is that is not a problem of the USB itself because it worked on another computer.

Comment: @Juan when you say it worked in the other computer, do you mean just that it started, or do you mean that the installation completed and successfully installed windows XP?

Comment: @barlop That it started. Can't really try it on another pc.

Comment: @Juan out of interest, if you try with the same usb stick, making a bootable dos usb with rufus on the computer where the windows one doesn't start, does it start?

Comment: @barlop It does. I just upgraded the BIOS with a DOS stick.

Comment: @Juan well, even if for some weird reason, the windows xp usb install starts on one computer, and doesn't start on another, I think you'll find that  it won't complete successfully even on the one it successfully starts on. There are some hacks you can use that might make XP install from USB. I  vaguely recall there might've been something about it on this forum (ignore google chrome's warning about the site, google  warnings aren't trustworthy)  http://www.911cd.net/forums/index.php  if chrome tries to stop you click details then 'visit this site' or use firefox

Comment: http://www.911cd.net/forums//index.php?showtopic=22857