# Why I cannot copy install.wim from Windows 7 ISO to USB (in linux env)

Tags: linux, usb, ntfs, iso-image

I need to make a USB bootable disk of Windows 7 ISO.

My USB is formatted to NTFS, ISO is not corrupt. I can copy install.wim elsewhere but I cannot copy it to USB. I even tried rsync.

### rsync error

```
sources/install.wim
rsync: writefd_unbuffered failed to write 4 bytes to socket [sender]: Broken pipe (32)
rsync: write failed on "/media/52E866F5450158A4/sources/install.wim": Input/output error (5)
rsync error: error in file IO (code 11) at receiver.c(322) [receiver=3.0.8]
```

### Stat for windows.vim

```
  File: `X15-65732 (2)/sources/install.wim'
  Size: 2188587580  Blocks: 4274600    IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 671984      Links: 1
Access: (0664/-rw-rw-r--)  Uid: ( 1000/    umur)   Gid: ( 1000/    umur)
Access: 2011-10-17 22:59:54.754619736 +0300
Modify: 2009-07-14 12:26:40.000000000 +0300
Change: 2011-10-17 22:55:47.327358410 +0300
```

### fdisk -l

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 8103 MB, 8103395328 bytes
196 heads, 32 sectors/track, 2523 cylinders, total 15826944 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xc3072e18

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1   *          32    15826943     7913456    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

### hdparm -I

```
/dev/sdd:
SG_IO: bad/missing sense data, sb[]:  70 00 05 00 00 00 00 0a 00 00 00 00 20 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

ATA device, with non-removable media
    Model Number:       UF�F�A����U]r���U   u��tF�f�`~
    Serial Number:      �@~|
    Firmware Revision:  ����V�
    Media Serial Num:   $I�vnladip raititnot baelErrrol aoidgn
    Media Manufacturer: o eparitgns syetmiM
Standards:
    Used: unknown (minor revision code 0x0c75) 
    Supported: 12 8 6 
    Likely used: 12
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   17218   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   128 0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY(may be)(cannot be disabled)
    Queue depth: 11
    Standby timer values: spec'd by Vendor
    R/W multiple sector transfer: Max = 0   Current = ?
    Recommended acoustic management value: 254, current value: 62
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: unknown
       *    reserved 69[0]
       *    reserved 69[1]
       *    reserved 69[3]
       *    reserved 69[4]
       *    reserved 69[7]
Security: 
    Master password revision code = 60253
    not supported
    not enabled
    not locked
    not frozen
    not expired: security count
    not supported: enhanced erase
    71112min for SECURITY ERASE UNIT. 172min for ENHANCED SECURITY ERASE UNIT.
Integrity word not set (found 0xaa55, expected 0x80a5)
```

Comment: Have you got another USB device to try?

Comment: all the others are less than 4gb. yet, i've seen that many people had experienced this problem, so it should be irrelevant from the usb device; yet hdparm results are little confusing

Comment: According to what you've posted, the install.wim is 2.1GB (2188587580), so that should fit on a USB that's <4GB (but >2.1GB)?  The hsparm info under "Model", "Media Serial" and such is pretty sketchy looking, hence why I suggest trying another USB device :)

Comment: all the flashdrives i have are 2 gb right now, except the one that i am using =(

Comment: possible duplicate of [Creating a Windows XP installation flash drive in linux](http://superuser.com/questions/58602/creating-a-windows-xp-installation-flash-drive-in-linux)

Comment: Why bother with NTFS? Windows Setup can boot perfectly fine from FAT32. You'd have to apply the appropriate boot sector, of course.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Well, the reason for this problem is because the file is >4.0 GB in size and the USB is formatted in FAT32 format. The max file size for FAT32 is 4GB. The max file size for FAT16 is only 2GB.

So how do you fix this problem? Well there are two ways you can go about it. You can either split the file into smaller pieces and then copy it to your external hard drive or you can convert the file system to NTFS, where there is no limit on file sizes.

Comment: Too bad you can't boot off of a USB that is NTFS-formatted. :(

Comment: Actually, there is a third option: you can also compress the install.wim file using wimlib (or dism on windows), see: https://tqdev.com/2019-cannot-copy-windows-10-install-wim

Comment: @Kon It is possible. Rufus makes such media.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem copying `install.wim` to USB flash drive (I tried several), so I changed the cluster size.

<kbd>Right Click</kbd> the drive, under USB, select `Format`, then change cluster size from 4096 (default) to 16 Kilobytes, and try to copy `install.wim` again.

Comment: You, sir, are a life saver!

Comment: @gretys unfortunately this will not work since the new install.wim is > 4GB, which cannot be put into FAT32. We need to use dism tool to split the wim image.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot copy `install.wim` to a FAT32 partition, because FAT32 partitions do not allow files larger than 4 GB and the `install.wim` file is (slightly) larger than 4 GB. You can recompress the `install.wim` with "wimlib-imagex" with compression level "solid" using the following command:

```
wimlib-imagex optimize install.wim --solid
```

You may have to install WimLib:

```
sudo apt install wimtools
```

On Windows the tool is called "dism" and the compression level "recovery".

Source: [tqdev.com](https://tqdev.com/2019-cannot-copy-windows-10-install-wim)

Comment: Hi. I have been going through the nightmare trying to compress the `install.wim` file but with no success. It spits out error code 77 saying the WIM file is read-only. I have added `sudo` in front of the command but it has still given me the same error. Do you know what could be the reason?

Comment: @akkab do you compress the file on ext3/ext4? Dont execute the compression on vFAT/FAT32

Comment: No, I am doing it on FAT32. Will it be readable by ubuntu as a drive from which I want to install Win10?

Comment: @akkab the compression should be executed on a drive that supports larger files (than 4GB).

Comment: You can add `--recompress --compress=LZMS:100` for extra space savings (~1GB).

Comment: @Avamander I tried your suggestion, but it didn't work for me (faster, larger size)

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't address the specifics, but when creating bootable USBs from ISOs I have never run into a manual copying process. I usually use something like unetbootn as described in [Create bootable windows 7 usb drive](http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/create-bootable-windows-7-usb-drive.html) have you tried something like this?

Comment: Of course I did=) I do use unetbootin for creating bootable usbs for linux, but for windows, the process is a little bit complicated. You have to copy the files and write a MBR for your windows version yourself.

Comment: It says that unetbootin can also prepare bootable usb's for windows but in my case it failed and it throw me to the boot console.

Answer (score 1):

What is the error message when you try simply copying the file? Can you copy other things to the flash drive or simply `touch` a file on it? It's possible that one of three things is happening here:

1. Your flash drive's filesystem is in a bad state, and you can't read/write to it. In this case, a reformat may help you out.
2. It's possible that, because the `install.wim` is so large, that your filesystem can't handle the size of the file. Again, a re-format with the appropriate block size may help you out.
3. The flash drive itself is dead. If a re-format doesn't fix the drive, you're better off finding something else.

You should be able to pick up a cheap 4GB for [as little as $4 USD](http://www.google.com/products/catalog?sugexp=chrome,mod=5&q=4gb%20flash%20drive&um=1&ie=UTF-28&tbm=shop&cid=17607437757817362548&sa=X&ei=7fm1T7SHDaOhiALkuPjLBg&ved=0CP4BEPMCMAE), so it shouldn't be the end of the world if it is indeed dead.

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a bit old, but in case anybody has this issue.  My ISB flash drive is 130gb and formated ntfs and boots to Win PE 4.0. I still had the Error that install.wim was too large to move over. so I simply copied the .iso over to the flash drive and used 7Zip to extract to a folder booted to WinPE dropped to D Drive and went into teh Win7x64 folder and ran setup. OS installed

Answer (score 1):

Right Click the drive, select Format, then change cluster size from 4096 megabytes (the default) to 16 Kilobytes and  filesystem to *exFAT* and now try to copy install.wim again.

Answer (score 1):

Simply use DISM command to split install.wim image to your desktop as follows:

```
Dism /Split-Image /ImageFile:F:\sources\install.wim /SWMFile:C:\users\USERNAME\install.swm /FileSize:3072
```

Where F:\sources is the original location of your install.wim (ex. mounted ISO file), you split it to multiple pieces to your desktop.

Then copy multiple *.SWM files from desktop to your FAT32 formatted USB stick or installation media.

More information [HERE](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/split-a-windows-image--wim--file-to-span-across-multiple-dvds?view=windows-11)

Comment: Another option would be to export the index required, as the individual indexes of the base OS are usually <4GB

Answer (score 0):

If unetbootin doesn't work, as @Dennis suggested, try [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/) (similar to unetbootin/universal USB installer). I can give it a .iso of a windows installer and a thumb drive, and it works like a charm. If it can't, it usually gives informative error messages.

Answer (score 0):

I've come across that problem myself while creating a bootable USB.

- On my first try, the copying process just stopped/froze.
- The second try, with Total Commander - same thing 99% and that's it.
- Third try (success), just regular copy/paste from Win7 CD/DVD -> USB and the same story, but this time I just let it be.

That third try, the time remaining started increasing but after 5 min progress bar moved again and the copying process was completed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this problem. I copied all other files seperately and left the install.wim until last. When I did this I walked away. It took about 5-10mins but copied successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry to revive an old thread but I didn't find a good answer on here. I'd like to share how I achieved this.

From the command line:

```
cd /dev/iso-location
sudo apt update && sudo apt install wimtools
wimlib-imagex split install.wim ~/Documents/install.swm 2000
```

Then, instead of copying install.wim onto the USB, copy all of the install.swm files. For me, as mine is a little over 4GB, I had 3 of them. Make sure there is no install.wim remaining on the USB drive (only the .swm files) and voila.

The `2000` at the end of the final command above limits the output .swm files to 2000MB. You can make this smaller / larger if you want; I used 2000 because of no particular reason.

> This is for Windows 10, by the way. My install.wim was located in `iso/sources/install.wim` so I moved the .swm files to `/usb/sources/install.swm` & `/usb/sources/install2.swm`
>
> What we have done here is split the .wim file in to smaller .swm files, so that  the FAT32 USB can hold the files and thus we can create a bootable USB at last.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to format your USB to `MS-DOS(FAT32)`, then install `wimlib` (*`brew install wimlib`*), then run the following command:

```
wimlib-imagex split /Volumes/<YOUR WINDOWS ISO>/sources/install.wim /Volumes/<YOUR_USB>/sources/install.swm 2000
```

I was having issues with 4000Mb, but 2000Mb worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

#### Split install.wim into 2 files

Install the following packages to split the install.wim file in 2 files on FAT32:

```
sudo apt-get install wimtools
```

Where you have mounted the iso split install.wim in 2:

```
wimlib-imagex split install.wim install.swm 4000
```

#### Preparing the USB key

Now install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install mtools
sudo apt-get install dosfstools
sudo apt-get install gparted
```

With your (soon bootable) usb key use Gparted and:
1/ unmount usb key
2/ device->create partition table-> BSD
3/ create a new FAT32 partition
4/ Select Apply

Disconnect and reconnect your usb key then proceed to copy all files from your windows iso to your usb key, while carefully replacing `install.wim` with `install.swm` and `install2.swm` instead

Once done you may now reboot and access bios (F2) to have the key being booted first and proceed with the installation of Windows.

Answer (score -1):

Skip, then,
You can just find the file (install.wim) in the sources folder of your iso and copy it
Then go to the sources folder in your usb and delete install.wim then paste the file out there

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).